# Calculating a student grade in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've got an HTMl form to input student names and grades in which should use JavaScript to calculate a grade that is then printed on the screen. My HTMl works fine if I comment the meat of my JavaScript out, but not if I don't. The error is somewhere in the code that I commented out, but I just can't find it (or them).

The HTML form will submit, alert the user, and show my message correctly as long as it is fed a concrete grade and score instead of trying to fetch it through getGrade() and getScore(). This is why I know the bug is in the JavaScript.

I've run the page in the JavaScript console to look for bugs, but there are no red flag errors.

This is my first HTML/JavaScript program, and I not very good at it. Anyway, it's a day late and in less than two hours, it will be two days late, so if anyone could help, I'd appreciate it hugely. Here's the code, sorry if it's too much:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Joe Peterson's Assignment 7</title>
  <script>
    function calculateGrade(){


      document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("p1").style.display = "block";
      var fname = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
      var lname = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
      var valMidterm = document.getElementById("MidtermScore").value;
      var valFinal = document.getElementById("FinalScore").value;
      var lMidterm = document.getElementById("MidtermLetter").value;
      var lFinal = document.getElementById("FinalLetter").value;
      var homeworkArray = document.getElementById("HomeworkScores").value.split(',');
      var classworkArray = document.getElementById("ActivityScores").value.split(',');
 /*     
      var s1 = new Student(fname, lname);
      for (var i = 0; i < classworkArray.length; i++)
        s1.addGradedActivity(classworkArray[i]);
      for (var i = 0; i < homeworkArray.length; i++)
        s1.addGradedHomework(homeworkArray[i]);
      s1.setMidterm(valMidterm, lMidterm);
      s1.setFinal(valFinal, lFinal);
      var grade = s1.getGrade();      
      var score = s1.getScore();
*/      
      document.getElementById("span1").innerHTML = (grade);
      document.getElementById("span2").innerHTML = (score);
      document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML = (fname);
      document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML = (lname);
      alert(document.getElementById("FirstName").value);
      return false;
    }
 /*   
    function Coursework(){
      var sum = 0;
      var num = 0;
      this.addScore = function(score){
      if (score < 0) {score = 0;}
        if (score > 100) {score = 100;}
        sum += score;
        num++;
      }
      this.getAverage = function(){
        return (sum/num);
      } 
    }

    function Exam(){
      var score = 0;
      var grade = "";
      this.Exam = function(Score, Grade)
      {
        if (Score < 0) {Score = 0;}
        if (Score > 100) {Score = 100;}
        score = Score;
        if (Grade != "A" && Grade != "B" && Grade !="C" 
                         && Grade !="D" && Grade != "F")
        {
            console.log("You have submitted a bad grade for an Exam, value of:G.");
            Grade = "F";
        }
        grade = Grade;
      }
      this.getScore = function(){
        return score;
      }
      this.getGrade = function(){
        return grade;
      }
    }

    function Student(){
      var firstName;
      var lastName;
      var midterm;
      var finalExam;
      var homework = new Coursework();
      var inclass = new Coursework();
      this.Student = function(first, last){
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
      }
      this.setMidterm = function(score, grade){
        midterm = new Exam(score, grade);
      }
      this.setFinal = function(score, grade){
        finalExam = new Exam(score, grade);
      }
      this.addGradedHomework = function(score){
        homework.addScore(score);
      }
      this.addGradedActivity = function(score){
        inclass.addScore(score);
      }

      this.getFinalGrade = function(totalScore)
      {
        var grade = totalGrade(totalScore);
        var grade2 = "F";
        var midGrade = this.convertGrade(midterm.getGrade());
        var finGrade = this.convertGrade(finalExam.getGrade());
        if (midGrade < finGrade)
        {
            grade2 = midterm.getGrade();
        }
        else
        {
            grade2 = finalExam.getGrade();
        }
        if (convertGrade(grade) > convertGrade(grade2))
            return(grade);
        else
            return(grade2);
      }

      this.totalGrade = function(totalScore)
      {
        var totalGrade = "F";
        if (totalScore >= 90)
            totalGrade = "A";
        else if (totalScore >= 80)
            totalGrade = "B";
        else if (totalScore >= 70)
            totalGrade = "C";
        else if (totalScore >= 60)
            totalGrade = "D";
        else 
            totalGrade = "F";
        return (totalGrade);
      }

      this.convertGrade = function(letter)
      {
        var num = 0;
        if (letter === "A")
            num = 4;
        else if (letter === "B")
            num = 3;
        else if (letter === "C")
            num = 2;
        else if (letter === "D")
            num = 1;
        else
            num = 0;
        return(num);
      }

      this.getScore = function()
      {
        var totalScore = 0;
        totalScore += inclass.getAverage() * .15;
        totalScore += homework.getAverage() * .25;
        totalScore += midterm.getScore() * .25;
        totalScore += finalExam.getScore() * .35;
        return totalScore;
      }

      this.getGrade = function()
      {
        var totalScore = 0;
        totalScore += inclass.getAverage() * .15;
        totalScore += homework.getAverage() * .25;
        totalScore += midterm.getScore() * .25;
        totalScore += finalExam.getScore() * .35;
        var grade = getFinalGrade(totalScore);
        return grade;
      }

    }
*/    

  </script>
</head>

<body>
<p><h1>Joe Peterson's Assignment 7</h1></p>
<form name="input" id="form1" onsubmit="return calculateGrade()" style="display:form">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="Joe"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" value="Peterson"><br>
Homework Scores (separate with commas): <input type="text" name="HomeworkScores" id="HomeworkScores" value="90, 80, 98"><br>
Activity Scores (separate with commas): <input type="text" name="ActivityScores" id="ActivityScores" value="71, 65, 96"><br>
Midterm Exam Percentage: <input type="text" name="MidtermScore" id="MidtermScore" value="91"><br>
Midterm Exam Letter Grade: <input type="text" name="MidtermLetter" id="MidtermLetter" value="A"><br>
Final Exam Percentage: <input type="text" name="FinalScore" id="FinalScore" value="75"><br>
Final Exam Letter Grade: <input type="text" name="FinalLetter" id="FinalLetter" value="C"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p id="p1" style="display:none">Final course grade for <span id="fname">Joe</span> <span id="lname">Peterson</span> is: <span id="span1">X</span> (<span id="span2">yy</span>%)</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use javascript debugger in what ever browser your using and it will generally give an indication where the javascript error is occuring.

Comment: HTML works fine without commenting out the JS.

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work fine?" What do expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: It outputs the words, "Joe Peter has the score, A (91%). If the JavaScript is left in, it says X, (yy%) instead, and just reloads the graph instead of continuing to show the grade sentence.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to use the debugger in Chrome, and I don't have time to download any third party stuff.

Comment: On chrome, just press Ctrl-Shift-J, the will bring up the debugger. From there you can go to the Console tab, it that will show your the javascript errors.

Comment: If this is for a grade, you need to learn the material to solve your problem. This issue requires basic debugging.

Comment: Intending the previos answer's comment; you may write multiple statements in `if..else` without brackets, seperating by commas.

Comment: T.V. - Yes, I do know how to look for errors in the JavaScript console. My errors definitely occur runtime. No red flags. Shawn Erquhart - That wasn't part of my question. Don't presume.

Comment: To start with, create a brand new button that calls `calculateGrade()`. E.g., <button onclick='calculateGrade()'>Click me</button>. The problem is you are submitting the form, and that causes the page to reload. In fact, I don't think you EVER want to *submit* your form. In any case, because the page is reloading you aren't seeing your JavaScript error. 

That should be a start for you.

Comment: @aquinas, the submit, alert, and reload is required for the assignment. If you run this code like I have it with your own values for grade and score, then it does exactly what I want it to. The problem is that the JavaScript is not returning the correct values for grade and score. Thanks though.

Comment: Trust me. Add the button and call calculate grade.

Comment: @aquinas - Alright, I tried it, but it does the exact same thing: flashes the sentence but without the correct values (just X and yy) and then reloads the chart. Commenting my JavaScript back out makes the two buttons do the same thing, which is the correct thing as long as I hard-code in a grade and score in the code.

Comment: @Jack. No  it doesn't. :) Go here: http://jsfiddle.net/t9wf67gd/. Hit F12 to open the JavaScript console. And then click the button.

Comment: @aquinas Awesome, thanks. JSFiddle displayed it differently than Chrome I guess and actually gave me an error! Finally! Any idea why it would say getFinalGrade() is not defined there even though it seems to be clearly defined just above getGrade()?

Comment: Hint #2: you're being very inconsistent with using "this". You want this.getGrade.